# Is the following sentence acceptable for you?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, modal-verbs

Is the following sentence acceptable for you?

> I humbly think that as a x, I could have increased my knowledge and experience in y by my previous studies.

And is this possible to change my knowledge and experience to my knowledge and experience**s**?

Comment: Khashayar, the use of *previous* casts the whole sentence into the past, IMHO. Did you mean to say you had the possibility to increase your knowledge through some studies you've done in the past?

Comment: Yes.I have already finished that courses.

Comment: This looks like proofreading to me. What specifically are we being asked about?

Comment: About tense of sentence and this "is this possible to change my knowledge and experience to my knowledge and experiences?"

Comment: I don't get why the previous studies bit is tagged on the sentence at all. You can't increase anything in the future 'by what you did in the past'. It just doesn't ring. Taken to ridiculous extreme - "I humbly think that as a mortician, I could increase my knowledge and experience in gardening by my previous studies [in Japanese kabuki theatre.]"... just doesn't work.

Comment: What about now.It has meaning now,right?

Comment: not really. Presuming a more logical progression, that x=lab assistant & y=particle physics, it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, Khashayar, now it has the sense of "I had the opportunity but I missed it".

Comment: I'm confused.What is the right tense?!

Comment: the problem, for me, isn't tense - it's the logical progression of three ideas. So far, there is no progression. Knowing what x, y & the previous studies were might help us.

Comment: I humbly think that as a veterinarian, I could have increased my knowledge and experience in animal source foods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I humbly think that as a x, I **could have increased** my knowledge and experience in y by my previous studies.

Means: "I had the opportunity but missed it".

> I humbly think that as a x, I **could increase** my knowledge and experience in y by my previous studies.

Means: "I had the opportunity" but tells nothing of whether you used the opportunity.

On a second thought, **could** seems to be used more in past-tense sentences to mean not "opportunity" but rather "ability", like:

> When I was studying for a veterinarian, I **could** easily memorise 100 pages of text in a couple of days. ("I was able to", not "I had the opportunity to")

You might remodel your sentence a bit, like this:

> I humbly think that my previous studies, made possible by the fact that I am an X, provided me with a good opportunity to increase my knowledge and experience.

This sentence, while also not explicitly announcing that you've indeed increased your skills through the studies, hints at it. And it looks a bit more natural.

You've provided another example sentence, with a more specific information:

> I humbly think that as a veterinarian, I could increase my knowledge and experience in animal source foods.

If you mean only your standard education of a veterinarian, you can say:

> I humbly think that my education as a veterinarian provided me with enough knowledge and experience to work in the animal source food field.

(a native English speaker might come up with more naturally sounding sentences)

Regarding experience and experiences: It will be more natural to use the word withous "S" at the end. You are referring to your "hands-on" knowledge in the field, hence you are using it as a non-count noun: you cannot measure experience in "bare numbers", quantify it. You can say

> I have 10 years of experience with animal feed.

But you cannot say:

> I had 15 experiences with animal feed. (Or at least the meaning will be different: it could mean, for instance, that you had 15 accidents with animal feed).

When one uses "my experiences", one usually means "the events that I was part of". Like, "I travelled to India and had many memorable experiences there. One was a visit to Kashmir."

Comment: So I think it is better to omit I humbly think that as a veterinarian from my sentence.Don't you think so?

Comment: With the salient info now plugged in, I think the 'previous studies' need differentiating. If they were 'med school for vets' then they don't need mentioning at all; all vets did those. if they were specific research, then that research needs singling out, with references. [not that your recast doesn't work as it is, I just think there ought to be the added, or removed, distinction]

Comment: This is going to be one of those question/answers that, after we have ironed out the tweaks, all comments need to go bye-bye. Feel free to kill mine, as & when necessary.

Comment: Good point.Thanks    And can I add S after experience like this knowledge and experiences?

Comment: @Khashayar - No, it's a non-count noun in the sense of "my hands-on knowledge in the field"

Comment: Thanks about "I humbly think that my education as a veterinarian provided me with enough knowledge and experience to work in the animal source food field."

Comment: @Khashayar: you're welcome! A tip: for proofreading you might use the site called "lang-8". I mean, for questions like "is this sentence okay". Here, the rules demand that you ask precise, specific questions, like your question on experience/experiences.

Comment: It's working nicely now, for me, as UK Eng. Kill the extraneous comments now, if you like - some of them are obviated by later tweaks.

Comment: OK.I understand.